# ScrollView Y Position

Tags: java, android

So I got two different ScrollView activities. At the bottom of both fullscreen ScrollViews I got a button that switch between them.

To give the second scrollView the same vertical position (hopefully) as the first one I use this:

```
((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView2)).fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

But that line of code will only give the same position if the user scrolled down 100% in the first ScrollView. Is there a way that I can get the current position of the first ScrollView, save it and then pass it to the next ScrollView when the button to switch View  is pressed? I mean is there a more precise way than:

```
(View.FOCUS_DOWN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you switch activities get the scroll position using

```
int scrollView1Y = scrollView1.getScrollY();
```

and pass that value as an extra to your second activity.  Then use

```
scrollView2.setScrollY(scrollView1Y);
```

Comment: Okay thanks I think I tried that and it did not work. But I don't know, will try again :)

Comment: Thanks i used this:  ((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView2)).post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView2)).setScrollY( scrollView1Y);
            }
        });

Comment: Works perfect on Android 9 but seems to be a lag on Android 6 where it starts at the top for a second